# MobileFirst Building a project WAR file with Ant

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to build the project .war file with Ant in MobileFirst Platform 6.3.

my build.xml has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="myProject" default="all">
        <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/Worklight-CLI/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <target name="all">
            <war-builder projectfolder="."
                destinationfolder="bin/war"
                warfile="bin/project.war"
            classesFolder="classes-folder"/>
       </target>
   </project>
```

When I execute the Ant script it throws the following error:

> [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource
>   com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties. It could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are using MFP 6.3, but in your XML you are pointing to "Worklight-CLI", which is **not** MFP 6.3, but 6.2 or older. Are you sure you're really using MFP 6.3?
It is also referring to the CLI. Are you certain you intend to use the CLI? No where in your question do you mention the CLI...

1. Verify you have installed the correct version of what you intend to use
2. Once you've installed the correct version, change the location attribute to:

> location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools/worklight-ant-builder.jar"

Comment: okay. i got it. Using Ant if i just want to build the app from MobileFirst 6.3, what should i do?.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote. Here is also the documentation topic: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html